# How to make all new Controls inherit new, Extended Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have extended from `Control`, like so:

```
public class Ctrl : Control
{
     public Boolean HasBorder { get; set; }
     public Boolean ShouldDrawBorder { get; set; }

     protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
     {
          if(CertainConditionIsMet)
          {
               // Then draw the border(s).
               if(this.BorderType == BorderTypes.LeftRight)
               {
                   // Draw left and right borders around this Ctrl.

               }
           }

           base.OnPaint(e);
     }
}
```

But, when I add a `new TextBox();` to the `Form` it still inherits from Control and not from `Ctrl`. How do I make all new Controls inherit from `Ctrl` instead?

Comment: That's not going to work.  C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, you'll need to consider encapsulation instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to manually re-create each control you want inheriting from `Ctrl`. e.g.

```
public class TextBoxCtrl : Ctrl
{
  /* implementation */
}
```

EDIT:

to avoid having to re-invent the wheel, I'd probably tackle it the following way:

First, make the added properties part of an interface so it's more a control you can hand-off:

```
public interface ICtrl
{
    Boolean HasBorder { get; set; }
    Boolean ShouldDrawBorder { get; set; }
}
```

next, work out a helper method (in a separate class) that will handle the UI enhancements:

```
public static class CtrlHelper
{
    public static void HandleUI(Control control, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // gain access to new properties
        ICtrl ctrl = control as ICtrl;
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            // perform the checks necessary and add the new UI changes
        }
    }
}
```

Next, work this implementation in to each control you want to customize:

```
public class TextBoxCtrl : ICtrl, TextBox
{
    #region ICtrl

    public Boolean HasBorder { get; set; }
    public Boolean ShouldDrawBorder { get; set; }

    #endregion

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        CtrlHelper.HandleUI(this, e);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
/* other controls */
```

Now you keep most of the original functionality of each control, keep its inheritance, and extend the functionality in one location with minimal effort (or change tot he original control).

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to avoid. +1. Is there no other way?

Comment: This isn't helpful, you cannot realistically implement your own TextBox control.

Comment: @HansPassant: if all the OP is doing is added a couple of borders to the control, this is well within the scope of possible.

Comment: Hoooooold on a second... If I implement things in `Ctrl`, then I re-create TextBox, I can just have TextBox recreation empty since it's implementation is already implemented in Ctrl, right?: `public class Ctrl : Control { // implementation... } public class TextBoxControl : Ctrl { } button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { TextBoxControl tbc = new TextBoxControl() { Location = new Point(0, 0) }; this.Controls.Add(tbc);` That would work wouldn't it? Or is it the wrong way to do it?

Comment: It isn't the borders that are hard to implement.  It is every *else* a TextBox control does.  Creating a text editor from scratch is hard work.  Clearly there's no benefit from re-using one method when you have to *add* a hundred to make up for that.  If you had some kind of encapsulation scheme in mind then that's very unclear from your answer.

Comment: The TextBox does not fire the OnPaint method.  You would have to override WndProc to get the paint message.  But that still wouldn't make it any easier to get a TextBox to paint a border correctly without flickering issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, unless you redo all the classes you need, for example:

```
public class ExtendedTextBox : Ctrl
{
    //implement the thing here
}
```